# Badboxes when using lipsum

Tags: lipsum

I have the following preamble

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Why does this generate bad boxes? It throws me 5.

Comment: Hyphenation is disallowed. You need hyphenation.

Comment: If you set text in narrow columns and disable hyphenation, you’re bound to have bad boxes.  You can improve matters by loading `microtype`, and improve them still more by allowing hyphenation and adding `babel` with Latin hyphenation rules.

Comment: @Thérèse How do I do that?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{microtype}`, `\usepackage[latin]{babel}`, and remove `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`.

Comment: There is also \sloppy and \raggedright

Comment: Why are you bothered about bad boxes when using `lipsum`? It is only intended for examples.

Comment: I just realised when writing in my language that this didn't happen. I thought it happened all the time.